# Disable Camel Log DSL using InterceptStrategy

Tags: logging, dsl, interceptor

I have an intercept strategy from where I want to control to send the exchange to Log DSL component. I can manage log uri via interceptor but cannot find how to control Log DSL component. 
Even if I need to set some property on camel exchange to control the logging level of Log DSL component that would do.
I already have an exchange formatter but that is not getting used (or at least not get fired) for Log DSL.

Any clues, pointers .....